# my simple prediction with linear regression wont execute

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, linear-regression, prediction

Below is my trial code:

```
from sklearn import linear_model

# plt.title("Time-independent variant student performance analysis")

x_train = [5, 9, 33, 25, 4]
y_train = [35, 2, 14 ,9, 7]
x_test = [14, 2, 8, 1, 11]

# create linear regression object
linear = linear_model.LinearRegression()

#train the model using the training sets and check score
linear.fit(x_train, y_train)
linear.score(x_train, y_train)

# predict output
predicted = linear.predict(x_test)
```

when run, this is the output:

> ValueError: Found arrays with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1 5]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redefine

```
x_train = [[5],[9],[33],[25],[4]]
y_train = [35,2,14,9,7]
x_test = [[14],[2],[8],[1],[11]]
```

From doc of `fit(X, y)`: `X` : numpy array or sparse matrix of shape `[n_samples,n_features]`

In your case, every example has only one feature.

Comment: I have run the simple regression, but no output displayed.Why? What am i doing wrong?

Comment: print `predicted` . It is your predictions.@user2979063

Comment: import numpy as np
x_train = np.array([5, 9, 33, 25, 4])
y_train = np.array([35, 2, 14 ,9, 7])
x_test = np.array([14,...])